# How to modify css to show slider text

Tags: html, css

Multiple CSS caption animation: http://jsfiddle.net/2nnao6m6/1/

Single animation: http://jsfiddle.net/nu4paxft/

HTML:

```
<div id="sample3" lang="is">

        <figure>
            <img src="olafsfjordur.png" width="200" height="200" alt="Ólafsfjörður" />
            <figcaption>Ólafsfjörður</figcaption>
        </figure>

    <!--end sample3--></div>
```

How can I modify the multiple css animation so the slider text is the same position as the single animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
.mainHolder figure:hover figcaption {
    left: -70px;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/2nnao6m6/2/

Change the values if you want to position it further in or out.

Comment: I was also looking to drop another ribbon from top left opposite of the bottom right one. I created two separate class but not sure how to achieve the positioning.

Comment: It will be the same principle but the initial positioning and animated properties and the hover state position will be different. You can create another question with your tried code.

Comment: I am about to do that. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490295/how-to-modify-position-with-css Thank you.