# Animated Ribbon with CSS - Ribbon Position

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvtt8kgz/

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 99%; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; margin: 15px 0 15px 0;">
        <div id="mPra" lang="is" class="mainHolder imgPra">
            <figure>
                <figcaption class="fig11">Group Profile</figcaption>
                <figcaption class="fig22">Edit</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; margin: 15px 0 15px 0;">
        <div id="mPro" lang="is" class="mainHolder imgPro">
            <figure>
                <figcaption class="fig11">Provider Profile</figcaption>
                <figcaption class="fig22">Edit</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 33%; float: left; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; margin: 15px 0 15px 0;">
        <div id="mSit" lang="is" class="mainHolder imgSit">
            <figure>
                <figcaption class="fig11">Site Profile</figcaption>
                <figcaption class="fig22">Edit</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear: both;" />
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; margin: 15px 0 15px 0;">
        <div id="mCli" lang="is" class="mainHolder imgCli">
            <figure>
                <figcaption class="fig11">Client Profile</figcaption>
                <figcaption class="fig22">Edit</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 50%; float: left; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; margin: 15px 0 15px 0;">
        <div id="mAcc" lang="is" class="mainHolder imgAcc">
            <figure>
                <figcaption class="fig11">Accountable Party Profile</figcaption>
                <figcaption class="fig22">Edit</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I modify the CSS for class `fig22`, so that it comes opposite (top left, along with the cutout matching the corners) of the class `fig11`.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Simple:

1-

```
.mainHolder figure {
    margin: 0; /* add this */
    padding: 0; /* add this */
}
```

2-

```
.mainHolder figcaption.fig11 {
    left: -30px; /* change this */
    bottom: 30px; /* change this */
}
.mainHolder figure:hover figcaption.fig22 {
    left: -120px; /* change this */
    top: 30px; /* change this */
}
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/jvtt8kgz/3/

Comment: Is there any way to smooth transition the slide out part? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, apply the transition to top and left properties, see updated demo.

Comment: Didn't even see that there. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the margin of the "figure" elements under "mainHolder" to have 0 margin.

```
.mainHolder figure {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Then you need to adjust the "left" values of your ribbons accordingly.

Comment: I added an image to show where I would like the `fig22` to appear when hovered over.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you. I played around with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `overflow: hidden` from `.mainHolder figure` and then adjusting the `:hover` for `figcaption.fig22`, thusly:

```
.mainHolder figure {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.mainHolder figure:hover figcaption.fig22 {
    left: -140px;
    top: -15px;
}
```